# corrplot how to change the color of the axis

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I am using the `corrplot` package how do I change the colour and size of the axis labels.

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method = "circle")
```

Simple example using the cars dataset how do I:

1) Change from red axis labels to black and size them differently.

2) Put the axis labels at the bottom rather than the top.

Thanks!

Comment: Ad 1: `corrplot(M, method = "circle", tl.col="black", tl.cex=seq(.5, 2, length.out=ncol(mtcars)))`.

Comment: thank you very much sorry had one more question how do i add the values inside the circles and color them black..thanks so much!